# getCurrentPostion() for MediaPlayer giving zero value in android

Tags: android, media-player

I have implemented a seekbar and it is working fine. I have a code that records the audio for 3 mins. The seekBar updates properly for all the devices while playing except(Moto X Play).

If i record the audio for around 20 seconds it works fine in Moto X Play also.. But when i record the audio for around a minute or more, then it is not updating on the UI but i can here the audio. the getCurrentPosition returns zero if the audio length is around 1 min or more in Moto X Play device.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. 
Here is the code snippet

```
public void startPlayingAudio() {

    GbLog.d(TAG, "The recorded audio is playing");
    ImageView playAudioImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.audioPlayButton);
    playAudioImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mode_pause);

    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayerSeekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    isPlayingCompleted = false;
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            isPlayingCompleted = true;
        }
    });
    mediaPlayerSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            System.out.println("onProgressChanged.");
            if (fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            GbLog.d(TAG, "onStartTrackingTouch");
        }


        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            GbLog.d(TAG, "onStopTrackingTouch");
        }
    });
    seekUpdate();
}`
```

and this is call for the update

```
  public void seekUpdate() {

    System.out.println("mediaPlayer.getDuration()::" + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    System.out.println("mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()::" + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    System.out.println("isPlayingCompleted::" + isPlayingCompleted);

    int getCurrent = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    mediaPlayerSeekBar.setProgress(getCurrent);
    mediaPlayerSeekHandler = new Handler();
    if (isPlayingCompleted) {
        mediaPlayerSeekHandler.removeCallbacks(updateSeekBar);
        mediaPlayerSeekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        stopPlayingAudio();
        mediaPlayerSeekBar.setProgress(0);
    } else {
        mediaPlayerSeekHandler.post(updateSeekBar);
    }
}

Runnable updateSeekBar = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        seekUpdate();
    }
};
```

Comment: `mediaPlayerSeekHandler.post(updateSeekBar)` why? why not with a delay? now you are posting hundreds (or more) `Runnable`s per second

Comment: How do i add delay and how much?

Comment: `"""How do i add delay?"""` read `Handler` documentation `"""and how much?"""` try different values

Comment: i have modified code to....mediaPlayerSeekHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBar,1000); Can u tell me what is the problem because it is still not working

Comment: what is on the logcat? and dont call `mediaPlayerSeekHandler = new Handler();` again and again...

Comment: 01-04 19:57:20.208    3803-3803/com.giftbig.mobile I/System.out﹕ isPlayingCompleted::false
01-04 19:57:20.210    3803-3803/com.giftbig.mobile I/System.out﹕ onProgressChanged.
01-04 19:57:21.212    3803-3803/com.giftbig.mobile I/System.out﹕ mediaPlayer.getDuration()::3093
01-04 19:57:21.215    3803-3803/com.giftbig.mobile I/System.out﹕ mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()::0
01-04 19:57:21.215    3803-3803/com.giftbig.mobile I/System.out﹕ isPlayingCompleted::false

Comment: mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() is having zero and it is happening with only Moto X Play... on other devices it works fine

Comment: so it is not playing

Comment: It is playing the audio but the seekBar UI is not updating

Comment: if `getCurrentPosition()` is always 0 it means it is not playing, what does `isPlaying()` return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99755/discussion-between-rahul-hawge-and-pskink).

Comment: also, `mediaPlayer.getDuration()::3093` so it is neither 3 mins nor ~20 secs